# Add a custom field per store view

Tags: checkout, database, adminhtml, multistore, forms

I need to add a custom field(drop-down list) for a store view, what is the conditional statement I need to display this, it would be nice to have it dynamic and have it added in the admin side. Would it be a custom extension?

Store 1.) Displays the checkout form out of the box
Store 2.) Displays the checkout form including an extra field that needs to be managed every month and added too. 
Store 3.) Displays the checkout form including an extra field (drop-down list) that has different data than Store 2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems more like a request rather than a question. What have you tried?

Comment: I know how to add a custom field to checkout, but not sure how it can be managed per store

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be creative and native - you could use `ifconfig` in the layout XML and add a `system.xml` admin attribute - with a store-level scope definition.

Then you could conditionally include/exclude that XML block based on the store view.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following link and pay close attention to the "Store Scope"

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields

Here is some more information on "Store Scopes"

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/understanding-store-scopes

Hope this helps!

Comment: sweet will take a look